# What was the memory limit after dockerizing node application?

Tags: node.js, docker

In my Node application I'm using caching mechanism, I'm confused and I'm wondering what would be the memory size of my application after dockerizing it?

I'm using `Node 10.16.0-jessie-slim` docker image.

**Dockerfile**

```
#Getting base image
FROM node:10.16.0-jessie-slim

#Maitainer
MAINTAINER Rajath

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install 
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 7234
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Can you provide more info like the `docker run` command you used to run the container.

Comment: Also what you mean by memory size, do you mean size of your application after dockerizing. Or the memory usage of your running nodejs application.

Comment: I'm using `docker run my-hello-world:1.0` command, and I want to know memory usage of nodejs application

Comment: Please check the question I just updated it with `dockerfile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dockerfile is nothing to do with memory limit or anything else related to resources.

AWS recommends 300-500 MB for each container,
[image]

So, now as per your local system, the memory depends on the application and the request per second. For the above container, I just modified your Dockerfile and have nodejs and simple express application its taking 34MB memory in idle state without any request.

```
FROM node:10.16.0-jessie-slim

#Maitainer
MAINTAINER Rajath
run apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git-core
RUN git clone https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-hello-node /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So here you can run `docker stats` to check memory and CPU consumed by container and maximum memory that can be allocated. 34MB by nodejs container and maximum is 15GB.

[image]

So this is all based on docker, now for further investigation, you can use portainer for details logs [portainer](https://www.portainer.io/installation/)

```
docker volume create portainer_data
 docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
```

Once portainer up then you can check

http://localhost:9000/#/containers/

Memory in idle state

[image]

CPU in idle state

[image]

After A bit load Test

[image]

[image]

> So, Now the question is does base image play role in memory? the answer is **Yes**, with a bit modification and set base image to **Alpine**, and there is the difference of `10MB` approx in container memory, the `alpine` base image taking from `25MB` to
>   `30MB` where, `node:10.16.0-jessie-slim` taking from `34MB` to `40MB`

modified the above image, set the base image to alpine which is the lightest image.

```
#Getting base image
#FROM node:10.16.0-jessie-slim
FROM node:alpine
#Maitainer
run apk add --no-cache git
MAINTAINER Rajath
#run apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git-core
RUN git clone https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-hello-node /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The alpine base image in the screenshot taking 28MB
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The memory is not specified inside a Dockerfile or an Docker-Image. Instead, you assign a Memory-Limit when starting your container using the `--memory` or `-m` Flag. If you did not assign any limit, the Container does not have one and will use the Servers maximal memory instead.

[Read more here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)